# use --ignore-table with MySQL while execute SQL file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have large SQL file and I need to import this file to my database under ubuntu and MySql

I used this command to export the database with **ignore** some tables from dump

```
  mysqldump -uroot -proot myDatabase --ignore-table=myDatabase.table1 > sql_backup.sql;
```

now I need to import it to another database and **ignore** some tables from import operation

how can i use `--ignore-table` option with this command

```
mysql -hlocalhost -root -proot newdb< sql_backup.sql
```

can I do that and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem like this every week. In my case i need to remove 2 tables when i import the database but need to dump it. After a quick search i tried `sed`, this what i'm doing, perhaps it could be useful to you:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '/`log_sessions`/ d' ${1} > dumpLog
sed '/`log_sessions_requests`/ d' dumpLog > ${2}
rm dumpLog
```

I use this script to clean the dump (and overwrite) removing all references to `log_sessions` and `log_sessions_requests`

If you change both names with your tables, it should work well.

Of course another solution is to do several dumps... but i think this is a better way.

**Edited**: Changed the script to avoid overwrite the main dump

How to use:

1. Save the script to a new file called cleanDB.sh
2. Call the script like this ./cleanDB.sh mainDump.sql filteredDump.sql

I think you get the idea, if need some explanation just tell me

Comment: Thanks with this command sed '/`log_sessions`/ d' ${1} > dumpLog  ar you remove the table from file??? sed its editor or Ubuntu command

Comment: it will remove all the lines in the file which have `\`log_sessions\`` and `\`log_sessions_requests\`` in them. And yes, sed is a command (GNU utility) available by default on Ubuntu

Comment: Exactly, if you only want to remove the inserts (perhaps you need the table but empty) change '/`log_sessions`/' with '/INSERT INTO `log_sessions`/' (If needed i can edit the answer with this)

Comment: @jetawe, if one of the answer was useful, mark as correct or upvote it to help other users

Answer (score 0):

Your sql_back.sql file contains normal ddl and insert statements. The mysql command will execute whatever commands given to it from the file.

You could manually open the file, find the table along with the related insert statements you want to ignore, and delete them from the file or comment them out and save it to a "sql_backup_with_ignored_tables.sql" file and run that one.

Comment: Thanks but I have 20 million record inside this file how can I remove it from the file on Ubuntu server with ssh connection

Comment: Please refer to the answer given by @sal00m to get an example of using `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you expect.

The later command "executes" the data you give it, and is not a dedicated 'backup' tool with options related to it.

First of all, if you have ignored the table while backing up, then it is not in the sql_backup.sql script, and you do not need to do any extra work.

If there is another table inside of `sql_backup.sql`, then two solutions I would suggest:

1. use `--ignore-table` of the table you do not want, while making backup.
2. manually or using text manipulating tool (like `sed`) edit the `sql_backup.sql` before executing.

Comment: Thanks but I have 20 million record inside this file how can I remove it from the file on Ubuntu server with ssh connection